# Can I use ‘fahren’ when the mode of transport is not decided?

Tags: translation, verb, usage

Suppose I am in London, and I am going to Paris. If I am just mentioning to someone the fact that I’ll soon go to Paris, can I use *fahren* as a generic translation of *to travel*?

I might  go by Eurostar, or I may fly, or I may drive, or catch the ferry. I may be undecided at this point or maybe I have decided but just don’t want to cover the mode of transport when I say to the other person ‘I am going to Paris’. Can I get away with using ‘Ich fahre nach Paris’? Or should *fahren* to be used only if I am traveling by ground transport (car, bus, train, …)?

Comment: Couldn't resist: " Wie geht denn dein neues Fahrrad?" - "Es geht nicht, es fährt!" - "Ok, also wie fährt dein neues Fahrrad?" - "Ach, es geht..."

Comment: to travel == reisen.  *Ich reise nach Paris* oder *Ich mache eine Reise nach Paris.*

Answer (score 27):

Yes. A common small-talk topic is “Wohin fahrt ihr dieses Jahr in den Urlaub?” and it is perfectly ok to answer “Wir fahren nach Island” even if you have your flight tickets booked already.

Same holds, of course, for London and Paris.

Comment: Feel welcome on German Language Stack Exchange. I’ll just point you to [tour] and [help] for consistency ;)

Comment: I never heard anyone say something like that, in my experience people use "fahren" and "fliegen" depending on what they mean. (North Germany)

Comment: "Ich gehe nach London" - sehr offensichtlich dass ich nicht zu Fuss nach London gehe.

Comment: But you would never answer "Ich gehe nach London" if you are asked "Wohin fährst du in den Urlaub". However, "Es geht nach London" would be perfectly fine. ;)

Comment: I might say "Ich gehe nach London" when telling someone I will be moving abroad permanently (e.g. for work). Maybe the neighbours: "Warum ziehen Sie aus?" - "Ich gehe nach London und arbeite bei X". Or maybe when talking about a semester of studying abroad. "Ich gehe für ein Semester nach London.".

Comment: waka: No, because "fahren" is already suggested in the question as a generic word, which is usually reflected in the answer. "Ich gehe nach London." is, however, a suitable answer to "Wohin gehst du in den Urlaub?", and also "Hast du Urlaubspläne?".

Answer (score 13):

Yes, but.

*Fahren* is a generic verb that can work for more or less any mode of transport: ‘Ich fahre mit dem Bus/der Bahn/der Fähre/dem Auto’. However, it is not used as often when you are actually flying. So it could be that people ask you ‘fährst du, oder fliegst du?’

So yes, *fahren* probably conveys the least possible amount of information, but not everybody will immediately connect *flying* to it. There are no real other options, though: *ich reise* implies an extended holiday and is rarely used; *ich bin … dort* only works if you care most about the date and *ich gehe* will either be misunderstood as moving altogether or walking.

Comment: +1 but I wouldn't carve out _ich reise_ too strongly as implying an extended holiday. It's also an _upscale_ style way to express simply going somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

*Fahren* is a generic word for traveling in much the same way as *to go*. You can ‘go’ to a place on a different continent, and the same is true with *fahren*. One important difference is that whereas *to go by plane* is already well established, *mit dem Flugzeug fahren/gehen* is currently still rejected by many, perhaps most, native speakers, though many already say it occasionally in careless colloquial speech. (In edited texts this always becomes *mit dem Flugzeug fliegen*.)

*Fahren* and *gehen* have different shades of meaning that can become important in certain contexts, to the point that you do not have free choice between them. *Fahren* stresses the act of traveling; *gehen* stresses the result:

- Wir fahren dieses Jahr nach Salzburg.
- Ich gehe für ein Semester nach Salzburg.

For going on holiday, *fahren* is generally preferred as if traveling were really what it’s all about, rather than being in a different location. For a temporary relocation, *gehen* is generally preferred because the act of traveling tends to vanish in the background compared to staying in a foreign place for a longer period.

Comment: "though many already say it occasionally" - do you have any reference for the claim that any native speaker would say "Ich gehe jetzt gleich mit einem Flugzeug." when they mean "Ich fliege jetzt gleich mit einem Flugzeug."? The only context in which I could imagine this is when a speaker incrementally adds parts to the sentence while speaking, e.g.: "Ich gehe nach Frankreich in den Urlaub ... mit dem Flugzeug."

Comment: Wie sieht es aus, wenn man in den Urlaub tatsächlich geht, sagen wir von Hamburg nach Altona, also zu Fuß, kann man dann auch 'fahren' sagen?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: By adding "jetzt gleich" you are moving the goal post because it sets up a context in which *fahren* is even more unlikely. We are talking about the grey area of linguistic innovations - things that children sometimes say and that many adults say and then immediately renounce when it is pointed out. Just try Google searches for "mit dem Flugzeug fahren" and variations.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich finde es schwer, über diesen seltsam konstruierten Sonderfall überhaupt eine Aussage zu treffen, aber *fahren* scheint mir hier abwegig, weil es keine Reise ist. Wenn man den Urlaub zu Hause verbringt, spricht man ja auch nicht von fahren.

Comment: Would you use *fahren* or *gehen* in this instance:  I've arrived to Frankfort airport and need to get (somehow, small plane, rent a car, bike, taxi, train, s-bahn, etc) to a close by suburb.  Would I ask someone "Wie fahre ich nach ____" or "Wie gehe ich nach ____" (or some other construction, like "Wie komme ich nach ___"?)  With the meaning being "How do I get to ____?".  Since I don't know my method of transport, what would the 'catch all' verb for this situation be?

Comment: @BruceWayne: In this case you would almost certainly choose *kommen* in colloquial German. An alternative in written German is *gelangen*, but that's only about as likely to be used in this kind of context as *reach*, and for the same reason.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use it the way you mentioned. It works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can say *fahren* and everybody will understand you, but people much more commonly say *fliegen* when they mean it.

Answer (score 1):

"Fahren" refers mostly to *ground* transportation. One can use "fahren" to refer to air or sea travel, but "fliegen" and "segeln" are more common words it those contexts.

That's because "fahren" has the connotations of being "driven." So you would not use fahren to refer to "walking," even though it's on the ground.

On the other hand, if there's doubt, as between car and air transportation, "fahren" is a good "catch all" verb. So it's more common to use "fahren" to refer to travel between say, Berlin and Paris or Rome, than between Berlin and London (the latter clearly requires some air or sea travel).

Comment: Well no. ‘Ich fahre mit dem Schiff nach Amerika’ sounds perfectly valid to me.

Comment: @I didn't say that fahren was "invalid" in this context, only that there was an alternative usage.

Answer (score 1):

To answer with *fahren* although you know you will fly is not precise and just can lead the one who asked to a wrong assumption. Better answer the general question with *fliegen* to prevent a misunderstanding. *Fahren* in the answer is just a unthoughtful try of synonym to *travel* which just is accepted with a certain tolerance due the question using that word.

Comment: I don’t understand the last part, beginning with “*Fahren* in the answer …”. Can you clarify what you wanted to say (possibly in a comment in German)?

Comment: I mean: (Die Benutzung von) *fahren* in der Antwort ist nur ein undurchdachter Versuch eines Synonyms für *travel*, der nur mit einer gewissen Toleranz aktzeptabel ist, weil das Wort in der Frage vorkommt."

Answer (score -1):

Nein.

> Ich gehe nach Paris.

oder

> Ich reise nach Paris.

Comment: "Ich gehe nach Paris" is wrong, if used for "reisen". I could imagine using it when e.g. moving to Paris, but not for a trip. Unless you actually walk, of course.

Comment: @Gerhard: "Ich gehe nach Paris um eine Gastprofessur anzutreten" würde man sagen, wenn die Form, wie man da hingelangt, nicht von Belang ist. 'Fahren' wäre hier falsch. Auch 'reisen' könnte ich da verwenden.

Comment: That's what I've said in my comment ;)

Comment: @Gerhard: As a German native speaker, I would disagree. "Ich gehe im Mai für 5 Tage nach Paris" sounds perfectly valid to me even if you don't travel by foot. "Fahren" may be more precise, but I wouldn't raise an eyebrow if someone used "gehen". This applies even more if the question asked was "Wohin gehst du in den Urlaub?".

Comment: @helm: as a German native speaker I disagree. I can see your first example to some extent as "I will stay in Paris for 5 days", but not as "travelling" - the distinction might be fine, but it is there imo. And it sounds a bit stilted to me. "Wohin gehst du in den Urlaub?" Is som ething i have never heard before - might be regional, if you are convinced it's common.

Comment: "gehen" ist in der Tat idiomatisch als generische Ausdrucksweise ungeachtet des Transportmittels - "Ich gehe zum Supermarkt." oder "Ich gehe in die Innenstadt." sagen nichts darüber aus, ob nicht doch ein Bus, eine Straßenbahn oder ein Auto im Spiel sind. Für größere Entfernungen ist jedoch "fahren" genauso generisch; "Ich fahre nach Griechenland." kann eine Reise per Auto, Schiff oder auch Flugzeug beschreiben, wenn man nicht gerade explizit den Transportmodus hervorheben will.

Comment: Man kann aber nicht sagen 'fahren', wenn man in Wahrheit zu Fuß geht.

Comment: @userunknown: In der Frage ging es zunächst einmal um die Reise von London nach Paris. Nur wenige legen diese Strecke zu Fuß zurück. Wie ich schon angedeutet habe, ist "gehen" tendenziell eher die generische Ausdrucksweise für kleinere Entfernungen, während "fahren" tendenziell eher für größere Entfernungen verwendet wird. Insbesondere scheint "fahren" vorrangig dann generisch gebraucht zu werden, wenn ein Fußweg durch die Entfernung ohnehin praktisch ausgeschlossen ist. Dadurch fällt es mir schwer, ein sinnvolles Beispiel zu finden. Möglicherweise ist das *genauso* aus meinem Kommentar ...

Comment: ... aber tatsächlich zu streichen beziehungsweise durch ein *fast* zu ersetzen. In beiden Fällen würde ich aber der Aussage "Nein." als direkte Antwort auf die Frage widersprechen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Diese Aussage passt in eine 80er-Jahre-Autofahrer-Gesellschaft, als die Leute ihren Sommerurlaub, ob Türkei, Italien oder Spanien noch weitgehend per Auto absolvierten. Heute gehen viele nach Australien in Urlaub, nach Afrika und Indonesien und legen auch Strecken wie London-Paris per Flugzeug zurück. "In Urlaub fahren" ist zwar noch idiomatisch, aber wenn man schon ahnt, dass der andere fliegt, wirkt fahren oft falsch: "Wohin geht's in Urlaub?" "Ich fahre nach Sydney!". Und London-Paris war ja auch nur ein Beispiel.

Comment: @userunknown: "wenn man schon ahnt, dass der andere fliegt, wirkt fahren oft falsch" - kann ich nicht nachempfinden, und ich finde auch etliche Beispiele von Aussagen à la "Wir fahren nach China", "Ich fahre in die USA." oder "Wir fahren nach Island.", deren Schreiber die Formulierung offenbar für natürlich hielten, obwohl mit Sicherheit nicht der Landweg (und vermutlich auch nicht der Seeweg) angedacht war. Auch würde ich "fahren" nicht zwingend mit einer "Autofahrer-Gesellschaft" in Verbindung bringen; Busse, Schiffe und Züge sind immerhin ebenso "fahrend" unterwegs.